# Django html template in production

Tags: django, static, production

im not sure if that is normal in django production deployment but im using django on a ubuntu and using nginx and gunicorn but im still able when i go to network tab to see all the html and javascript code . i have debug mode False and followed different tutorials but none shows or explain the expected behavior , like is it normal to see all the static files in the source and network and the code within those files ?

Comment: Yes it's normal.

Comment: You can do the same here in stackoverflow for example. Every html, css, javascript gets sent to your browser and is then interpreted by your browser. But for that these files have to be on your computer. So for sure you can access them in plain code.

Comment: But that means your code anyone can access ? like at least the javascript and html ?